# Append element only once

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, append

I have a responsive e-commerce template with a navigation bar that, when the window is resized below a certain break-point, stacks vertically.

The menu items that have children are appended an "expander". When clicked, this expands the corresponding submenu.

The function:

```
    function breakPointHendle(){
      elm.find('li').each(function() {
        if($(window).width() <= defaults.breakPoint) {
          if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
            $(this).append('<i class="expander fa fa-angle-down"></i>');
          }
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("parent");
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          $(this).find('.expander').remove(); 
          $(this).find('ul').removeAttr("style"); 
          $(hamburger).removeClass("active"); 
        }
      }); 

      $("i.expander").click(function() {
        if (!$(this).parent('li').hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).parent('li').children('ul').slideDown(defaults.slideDownTime);
          $(this).parent('li').addClass("active");
        } else {
          $(this).parent('li').children('ul').slideUp(defaults.slideUpTime);
          $(this).parent('li').removeClass("active");
        }
      });  
    };

    breakPointHendle();
    $(window).resize(breakPointHendle);
```

The fact that **breakPointHendle()** is *also called on window resize*, results in the inconvenience that, when the window is resized from small (below the break point) to *smaller* (even *more* below the break point), `<i class="expander fa fa-angle-down">` is **appended repeatedly**. So we get lots of expanders instead of just one.

How should the function e modified to avoid this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is not recommended to do dom manipulations inside the call back of window resize event. It will drain the performance. But still, if you want to do the same thing, then i would advise you to use the following code.

```
function breakPointHendle(){
      elm.find('li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("parent"); //---moved the line here
        $(this).find('.expander').remove(); //---moved the line here 
        if($(window).width() <= defaults.breakPoint) {
          if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
            $(this).append('<i class="expander fa fa-angle-down"></i>');
          }
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          $(this).find('ul').removeAttr("style"); 
          $(hamburger).removeClass("active"); 
        }
      });
     ....rest of the function definition.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a variable to track it's state, something like expanderstate, then set it to 0,1 (false/true) if its expanded or not, and check that the state is not equal to the expanded before allowing your expansion code to run.